# How to parse ASCII HEX FLOAT in Javascript for data returned from a serial device

Tags: javascript, serial-port

I have a piece of returned code from a (serial) device. I have 4 bytes of information that I need to get a usable, human-readable value from.

I tried a lot of code examples from the Internet, but I can't get a grip on it.

Here is an example of an outcome, but no formula for how to do this in JavaScript:

```
34 32 33 39 37 30 41 34 Bus voltage-float: A4703942=46.36
// ( so Voltage is 46.36 )
```

How do I get this from the Hex `A4703942` in JavaScript?

I know it has something to do with a float, little or big endian... yes?

Answer (score 0):

Check the below URL

```
http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/32bit.html
```

In the above URL, you enter the string 423970A4, which is the reverse(because of that end-ian stuff) of the your bytes string and click on compute, You will get the 46.36.

The JavaScript found in this URL page's source would help you for this conversion.

Comment: Thank you. thats exactly the conversion i need.

i searched the source of that page , but too hard for me to find the piece of code doing the conversion ( sorry low skills ) , i did see a parseInt, but thats it.  i need fewer lines to under stand. 
"
EEE-754 Floating-Point Conversion
From 32-bit Hexadecimal Representation
To Decimal Floating-Point"
is probably the best way and better title tot this btw.

Comment: i found on the web that in Python it is : input : 

41C41DC3
( formula in PyThon )
('!f', '\x41\xc4\x1d\xc3')

results in:
(24.514532089233398,) which is the same formula i need here i ques. but how to wrap that in javascript ( prefer rounded to 2 digits )

Comment: Please provide that python formula link.

Comment: here is the link for the formula in Python :  http://my.control.com/thread/1252163123

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question more or less :

//extract usable data from the returned Hex

```
function hex2float(num) {
var sign = (num & 0x80000000) ? -1 : 1;
var exponent = ((num >> 23) & 0xff) - 127;
var mantissa = 1 + ((num & 0x7fffff) / 0x7fffff);
return sign * mantissa * Math.pow(2, exponent);
}
```

//make it a nice 4 digits number

```
function roundToTwo(num) {    
return +(Math.round(num + "e+2")  + "e-2");
}


print or whatever (roundToTwo(hex2float("0x"+<yourhexInput>)));[/CODE]
```

( sometimes there is the need to flip the bytes/Hex to become the right input )

for example :

```
function swap32(val) {
return ((val & 0xFF) << 24)
       | ((val & 0xFF00) << 8)
       | ((val >> 8) & 0xFF00)
       | ((val >> 24) & 0xFF);
}
```